# PySide6 & WSL2: ImportError: libEGL.so.1

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pyside6

I'm using isolated with poetry/venv Python: 3.11.2 with Ubuntu WSL2 22.04

```bash
python app.py
```

Gives me the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lara/projects/qtapp/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
ImportError: libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**app.py:**

```py
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

app = QGuiApplication()
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

engine.load("myqmlfile.qml")

app.exec()
```

**pyproject.toml dependencies**

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.11,<3.12"
pyside6 = "^6.4.3"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.2.2"
pytest-cov = "^4.0.0"
isort = "^5.12.0"
black = "^23.3.0"
poethepoet = "^0.19.0"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libEGL.so.1&mode=exactfilename&suite=kinetic&arch=any) to figure out which package provides a certain file. In this case it's `libegl1`. Install it in WSL with:

```
apt install libegl1
```